# Are there any ``sophisticated'' mathematical modelling where they solve for the utility function?

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, utility, dynamic-programming, continuous-time

Are there any references in literature of any ``sophisticated'' mathematical modelling where they solve for the utility function under specific conditions using differential equations theory?

In such cases there maybe examples of dynamic market microstructure, where the parameter of risk aversion is time varying as well.

Any reference would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand exactly your question, or if you are asking for some particular class of models, but optimal control theory, and in general control theory, in continuos time make use of differential equations, they are included in the subject of 'controlled differential equations', and make use of the theory of differential equations.